# Is there a KDTree that provides an iterator in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy, kdtree

A KDTree is a tree indexed by N-D position in space. If I have an item with coordinate `[1,2,3]` and another item with coordinate `[1.0001,2,3]`, then a `KDTree` would return this nearest neighbor in a single `O(logN)` operation.

I have an algorithmic approach where I would like to sort the whole set of items in the KDTree by distance from the incident object.

```
incident_obj_coords = coords(incident_obj)
sorting = myKDTree.query(incident_obj_coords, count=len(myKdTree))
```

Then, I proceed along my sorting to find the best item:

```
score_threshold = 0.95
best_score = -inf
best_item = None
for item in sorting:
    score = similarity(item, incident_obj)
    if score > best_score:
        best_item = item
        best_score = score
    if score > score_threshold:
        break
```

Well, the above situation has complexity `O(N*log(N))`; what I would like is an `O(log(N))` amortized runtime.

In order to get an `O(log(N))` amortized runtime during the query, I need a `KDTree.query_iterator` that only gets the *next* item in the query when I need it (lazily):

```
score_threshold = 0.95
best_score = -inf
best_item = None
kd_it = myKDTree.query_iterator(incident_obj_coords)
while True:
    nxt = next(kd_it,None)
    
    if nxt is None:
        break
    
    score = similarity(item, incident_obj)

    if score > best_score:
        best_item = item
        best_score = score

    if score > score_threshold:
        break
```

Is there a `KDTree` in the python3 toolkit that can provide this sort of incremental search?

Comment: other than `sklearn.neighbors.KDTree`?  There are lots of SO about that.

Comment: @hpaulj can I get a query iterator from that one? I can try re-forming this question; I did not see an easy way there?

Comment: You can read its docs just as well as I can :(